# ssrs: Empty space before vertical axis label

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Is there a way in SSRS where I can minimize the space between the border of the chart and vertical axis labels?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have some control over this.

Say I have a simple chart:

[image]

Look at the **Chart** -> **Chart Areas** property:

[image]

You can control the position of items in the chart with the various **CustomInnerPlotPosition** and **CustomPosition** values.

These are all disabled by default:

[image]

However, you can enable and change to control the chart rendering:

[image]

Here I set **CustomPosition** -> **Left** to *0*.

Default properties:

[image]

Updated properties:

[image]

You can see this has reduced the whitespace. Depends on your chart, but maybe this will be enough.

Read more at [Fit Chart Labels Perfectly in Reporting Services](http://www.douglane.net/fit-chart-labels-in-ssrs/).